# Joining multiple tables using JPA @SecondaryTables

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa

I need to join 3 tables where A.id == B.id and B.id == C.id using JPA @SecondaryTables where I need to map these tables to a single entity. what is the way I should I should try?

Answer (score 2):

Since A.ID = B.ID = C.ID, you can just have 2 secondary tables, with the relationship A.ID = B.ID, and A.ID = C.ID.  Your "main" table will be A, and B and C are your secondary tables.  You can reference the table as follows in your column declaration.  (many other parameters in the annotations left out for brevity)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "A")
@SecondaryTables({
  @SecondaryTable(name="B", @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="ID", referencedColumnName="ID")),  
  @SecondaryTable(name="C",  @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="ID", referencedColumnName="ID"))
})
public Claass Blah {
  @ID
  private int id;

  @Column(table = "B")
  private String someColumn;

  @Column(table = "C")
  private String someOtherColumn;

etc...
}
```

Comment: I have tried that but C.id is referencing to A.id. It is like this
A.id = B.id and A.id = C.id what I need is  A.id == B.id and B.id == C.id

Comment: I'm not understanding you.  If A.id = B.id, and B.id = C.id, then by transitivity, A.id = C.id

Comment: yes that is correct but what I need is something like this A.id = B.id and B.did = C.did
There is no relationship like A.id = C.id

Comment: I see, so the id for the two relationships is separate?  Do you have to have the same class?  If not, you can create 2 classes, one of which has a secondary table, the other of which has a @OneToOne relationship with the first one.